# Linux kernel compile error

Tags: linux, unix, compilation, kernel

I cloned the kernel sources from Linus's github, I made a little modification to the usbhid driver (thats compiles fine as a module, no errors), but if I try to build the whole kernel, I get this error:

```
AR      drivers/gpu/drm/built-in.o
AR      drivers/gpu/built-in.o
Makefile:1023: recipe for target 'drivers' failed
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
```

And thats all nothing specific. What could be the problem?

Comment: This is the 1021-1023th line of the makefile:
`PHONY += $(vmlinux-dirs)
$(vmlinux-dirs): prepare scripts
 $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=$@`

Comment: There is should be **error message** describing what **exactly** is wrong. If you build the kernel with `-j` option, find the error message several lines above (or do not use `-j` option while debug a problem).

Comment: I searched for error messages, but I didn't find one anywhere in the terminal output, but I'll try without the `-j` tag

Comment: Can you post the changes you made?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: 9-15-18 This issue is resolved.. The kernel will now compile with the commands I have given below.**

Same issue here. 4.19.0-rc3 will not compile on the Threadripper 2990WX. BTW, I am currently running 4.19.0-rc2 with no issues.

These are the commands I used. Please note, I also tried without the LD static flag.

```
wget https://git.kernel.org/torvalds/t/linux-4.19-rc3.tar.gz && tar -xzf linux-4.19-rc3.tar.gz && cd linux-4.19-rc3 && make -j 64 clean && make -j 64 mrproper &&  zcat /proc/config.gz >> ./.config && LDFLAGS=--static make -j 64
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please add this as a comment to the question. It does not provide an answer to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your config file. I have faced the same issue before and and appears to be due to a missing `CONFIG` option in the `.config` file generated through `make menuconfig`.

You need to add these two CONFIG options in your .config file:

```
CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE_DIR="lib/firmware"
CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE="<name_of_firmware_along_with_path>"
```

In some platforms, the GPU uses firmware that needs to be built-in by stitching it with kernel. This firmware is placed in the directory path provided by `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE` option while building the kernel. And unless we don't provide `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE_DIR` path to tell the kernel where to pick this firmware from, the above build failure occurs.